# Extract unique US zipcodes (5 digits optionally followed by hyphen and 4 digits) from addresses

Tags: r, regex, gis

I'm looking for U.S. zipcodes in a df of addresses and postal codes. The records are unnormalised and contain data entry errors. Normal zipcodes are 5-digit numbers. I'm also looking for 4-digit numbers in the postal code field because the leading 0 may have been dropped by inadvertent conversion to a numeric value. 5-digit zipcodes can be followed by a hyphen and 4 digits, which I'd also like to capture. I expect only one zipcode in the postal code field, but it's possible there might be several in the address field because some people type two addresses in a form meant for only one. I want to look for zipcodes in addresses only if none is found in postal codes, because 5-digit street numbers in addresses would yield too many false positives. I realise addresses outside the U.S. will yield false positives if the local postal code matches the U.S. format.

My desired outcome is a new zip_code column of strings of unique found zipcodes separated by "/" (if multiple), with a leading 0 added to 4-digit zipcodes, or an empty string if nothing is found.

Here is my attempt, which totally doesn't work:

```
pc <- offices$postal_code[offices$postal_code != ""]
offices$zip_code[offices$postal_code != ""] <- unlist(lapply(pc, function(x) {
  pczc <- sub("(?<!\\d)(\\d{5}\\-\\d{4}|\\d{4,5})(?!\\d)", "\\2", x, perl = T)
  pczc <- ifelse(nchar(pczc) == 4, paste0("0", pczc), pczc)
  return(pczc)
  }))

ad <- offices$address[offices$zip_code == ""]
adzc <- regmatches(ad, gregexpr("(?<!\\d)(\\d{5}\\-\\d{4}|\\d{5})(?!\\d)", ad, perl = T))
offices$zip_code[offices$zip_code != ""] <- paste(unique(adzc), collapse = "/")
```

My regex don't work. Also, there may be a faster way of doing this (I have a lot of addresses). I've thought of merging the two fields first, but the problem with that approach is that 4-digit street numbers in the address field would be confused with zipcodes missing a leading 0, which can only occur in the postal code field. (There are also 5-digit street numbers, but I guess that can't be helped.)

Here's a sample of df offices (which doesn't include all possible use cases, e.g. either field may be empty):

```
structure(list(address = c("Headquarters 2355 E. Camelback Road Suite 300 Phoenix", 
"Headquarters 1401 Constitution Ave NW  Washington", "Headquarters 80 State Street 7th Floor  Albany", 
"Headquarters Spray Gaarde 46  Nieuwegein", "HQ 1055 Washington Blvd., 7th Floor  Stamford", 
"Headquarters Village Khubavali, PO Paud Taluka Mulshi  Pune", 
"Headquarters 231 Lagrange Street  Boston", "Headquarters 401 Chestnut St Suite 410 Chattanooga", 
"Israel Office st. ha Rav Bar Shaul 6  Rehovot", "Headquarters 7721 New Market Street  Olympia", 
"HQ Bernrieder Str. 15  Niederwinkling", "Headquarters 2810 Sydney Road  Plant City", 
"Headquarters 1350 Avenue of the Americas 9th Floor New York", 
"Headquarters Askanischer Platz 3  Berlin", "Australian Head Office Level 2, 145 Flinders Lane  Melbourne", 
"HQ 13303 Washington Avenue  Racine", "HQ 9150 E. Del Camino Dr., Ste 112  Scottsdale", 
"Arcadia Corporate Merchandise Ltd - Promotional Giveaways Grove Place, Wellington Road  High Wycombe", 
"Israel Office Shorashim, D.N.Misgav  ", "HQ 6009 Penn Avenue S.  Minneapolis"
), postal_code = c("85016", "20230", "12207", "3436", "6901", 
"412 108", "2132", "37402", "7625149", "98501", "94559", "33566-1173", 
"10019", "10963", "3000", "53406", "85258", "HP12 3PR", "20164", 
"55419")), .Names = c("address", "postal_code"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on the example?

Comment: what would be the expected result based on this dataframe? As such, your explanation could be simplified (providing the expected result would help a lot as well!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following cleans up the `postal_code` column, but you didn't provide a data frame slice with zips in the address field so without knowing what the "real world" data looks like in that column it'd be a potential time sink w/o efficacy.  I can add the zip extraction from the address field once you provide more representative data for your question.

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

df$zip_1 <- stri_trim_both(df$postal_code) %>%
  stri_match_last_regex("((?:[[:digit:]]{5}-[[:digit:]]{4})|(?:[[:digit:]]{4,5}))") %>%
  ifelse(nchar(.)==4, 0 %s+% ., .) %>%
  .[,2]

df[,2:3]
##    postal_code      zip_1
## 1        85016      85016
## 2        20230      20230
## 4        12207      12207
## 5         3436      03436
## 6         6901      06901
## 8      412 108       <NA>
## 10        2132      02132
## 11       37402      37402
## 12     7625149      76251
## 14       98501      98501
## 15       94559      94559
## 18  33566-1173 33566-1173
## 19       10019      10019
## 21       10963      10963
## 22        3000      03000
## 23       53406      53406
## 24       85258      85258
## 25    HP12 3PR       <NA>
## 27       20164      20164
## 28       55419      55419
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't find an example of zipcode in address now because I have 358,000 records and there are many 5-digit street numbers, but I can't discount it either.

Comment: Technically, this is the solution to the question I asked, but @dimitris_ps's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41395573/7114709) is the solution to my larger problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing some complex `regex` you could use `googlemapsapi`. I am sure there is a R package, but the following code should help.

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)


getInfo <- function(data, address){

    mURL <- "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" %>% 
      paste0(unlist(data[address])) %>% gsub("Headquarters|HQ", "", .) %>% sapply(URLencode)

    temp <- lapply(mURL, function(y) {
                info <- read_html(y) %>% html_text %>% fromJSON(simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
                if(length(info$results)){
                    info <- info[[1]]$address_components[[1]] %>% as.data.frame %>% select(-short_name)
                    info$types <- sapply(info$types, function(x) x[1])
                    info %<>% group_by(types) %>% summarize(long_name=toString(long_name)) %>% 
                             select(long_name, types) %>% ungroup
                    info %<>% spread(types, long_name)
                } else {
                  info <- data.frame(administrative_area_level_1=NA, administrative_area_level_2=NA, 
                                     country=NA, locality=NA, neighborhood=NA, postal_code=NA, 
                                     route=NA, street_number=NA, subpremise=NA)
                }
                info
      }) %>% rbindlist(fill=TRUE)

cbind(data, temp)

}

df2 <- getInfo(df, "address")
```

Test it out on a small subset of your `data.frame` which i assumed is named `df`. 
You can read more on the [`googlemapsapi`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

```
df2 %>% View
```

[image]

Comment: This blows my mind! I have a few questions if you don't mind. 1) There's 358,000 records. Will the API stall or reject the calls if I try to do everything at once? 2) Your function takes out non geographic words (like "HQ") first. Will calls fail if there are any non geographic words?

Comment: 1) Unfortunately i see from the `google maps api` that you can have up to 2,500 requests per day. $0.50 USD / 1,000 additional requests, up to 100,000 daily, if billing is enabled. 
2) It will return NA

Comment: https://github.com/Datactuariat/Rpostal will take some elbow grease to get working but it'll normalize all your addresses pretty well w/o the crutch of an external, rate-limited API. Much like the R fortune for `parse()` if the answer is "Google Geocode" you are probably asking the wrong question.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks for the tip about Rpostal. I'll look into it. I need to get the county info for my addresses so I can aggregate address-level data into MSAs. The Google API is going to give me the county info. How is that the wrong question?

Comment: rate-limited-cum-     APIs rarely are options for most folks. If you can wait days or have cash, great. most people don't.

Comment: @dimitri_ps For address "Euro House Euro Business Park Little Island Cork Cork", the function returns "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (4, 5)". The error comes from instruction `info %<>% spread(types, long_name)}`. This is because the preceding instruction `info$types <- sapply(info$types, function(x) x[1])` returns duplicate _locality_. Your input would be much appreciated.

Comment: @syre I have updated my answer to account for this. I have added the code `info %<>% group_by(types) %>% summarize(long_name=toString(long_name)) %>% 
                             select(long_name, types) %>% ungroup`

Comment: @dimitri_ps I've found another bug. For "Berlin Berlin", `info[[1]]$address_components %>% as.data.frame` returns
"Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 5". Apparently, it's because Google returns two different addresses.

Comment: @syre, i have updated my answer. Instead of `info[[1]]$address_components` i have `info[[1]]$address_components[[1]]` i.e. keeping only the first address if it is returning more than one.